# Is big O notation additive?

Tags: time-complexity, asymptotics

For example, I have one program that requires $O(i)$ time complexity, and a second program requires $O(j)$ time complexity. Would the total time complexity be $O(i+j)$? And why?

Comment: Have you tried *proving* your suspicions using the *definition* of big O?

Comment: Following the definition it should be O(max(i, j)) ?

Comment: It is true that $i+j = O(\max(i,j))$, and it can be proved from the definition of big O. In fact, $i + j = \Theta(\max(i,j))$, since $\max(i,j) \leq i + j \leq 2\max(i,j)$.

Comment: Thanks, so that I have I i+j = n, I can claim the overall complexity is O(n)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $f(n) = O(A(n))$ and $g(n) = O(B(n))$ then $f(n) + g(n) = O(A(n) + B(n)) = O(\max(A(n),B(n))$. These are standard properties of big O, which follow almost directly from the definitions.